# htaccess set expiry of js

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I use below code in my htaccess for leverage browser cache,it has set expiry of 1month for
javascript but when I test this google page speed insight the it asks for  increase various js expiry and it shows set as 2 days as default why it happens?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 11):

Try setting:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/json "access 1 month"          // Thanks to David Goss
```

See also: http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2010/05/leverage-browser-caching-increase-website-speed/

Comment: Yep, also worth adding a line for `application/json` in case you do any AJAX stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I had just had the first one, and it wasn't doing anything. Added your full set, and now the correct expirations are showing up in the headers that are sent.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"

ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 years"

ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 years"
```

Links:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/apache-module-mod-expires